# Миграция данных при публикации проекта ASP.NET Core 3.1 на сервере IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, iis

День добрый!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с вопросом запуска приложения **asp.net core 3.1** на сервере **iis**.
Собственно вопрос: каким образом необходимо создавать и подключать БД на сервере при публикации проекта?
Файлы проекта публикую в папку *inetpub/wwwwroot/[название проекта]*.
Устанавливаю **MSSQL Server Management Studio 18**. В ней создаю БД с названием, аналогичным БД в моем рабочем проекте Visual Studio. Через VS копирую базу из моего проекта в MSSQL SMS. В Management Studio в результате создается пустая база со всеми необходимыми таблицами.
Далее прописываю connectionStrings к БД.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-7J81BBU\\SQLEXPRESS2017;Initial Catalog=EmployeeTesting;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False",
    "EmployeeTestingIdentity": "Data Source=DESKTOP-7J81BBU\\SQLEXPRESS2017;Initial Catalog=EmployeeTesting;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
```

При запуске сайта в iis выдает ошибку:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EmplTest\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      CREATE DATABASE [EmployeeTesting];
Application startup exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Полностью ошибку цитировать не вижу смысла.
В тексте ошибки есть еще моменты которые мне кажутся важными: присутствуют ссылки на строки к моему рабочему проекту указывающие на строки в файлах Startup и Program
D:\MyProjects\Projects_New_ASP_NET_Core_MVC\EmployeeTesting\EmployeeTesting\Startup.cs:line 95
D:\MyProjects\Projects_New_ASP_NET_Core_MVC\EmployeeTesting\EmployeeTesting\Program.cs:line 19

если нужно код этих строк из проекта скину?!
Заранее прошу прощения если задаю совсем глупые вопросы, никогда не работал ни с IIS ни с MSSQLSMS. Всегда использовал SQL LocalDB.

Comment: Ваше приложение подключается к уже готовой БД или пытается создать новую? И покажите строку соединения.

Comment: Приложение подключается к готовой базе MSSQL, т.е в ней уже присутствуют все таблицы аналогичные базе из рабочего проекта VS. Но база пуста - не заполненна начальными данными.
Мое рабочее приложение в VS при первом запуске, заполняет БД начальными данными, если они отсутствуют.

Comment: Возможно причина в том, что при запуске сервера iis, не получается провести миграцию данных, тоесть заполнить БД на сервере MSSQL?!

Answer (score 0):

*Проблему разрешил таким способом:*

- Во первых, нет необходимости предварительно создавать БД, в моем случае приложение
  создает ее само.

1. Удалил ранее созданную вручную базу из MSSQL SMS.
2. Необходимо в SMS в папке Security/Logins создать нового пользователя БД
   и назвать его IIS APPPOOL\[название вашего пулла]
3. Далее зайти в созданного пользователя и в настройках, во кладке Server Roles, указать public и sysadmin
4. Также в моем случае была измененна строка подключения:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-7J81BBU\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EmployeeTesting;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "EmployeeTestingIdentity": "Server=DESKTOP-7J81BBU\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EmployeeTesting;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

После этих действий можно запускать сайт в IIS сервере.
Базы создаются автоматически и заполняются всеми необходимыми данными.